# Everything is Fine On PHP mail function but I'm not receiving any mail in my account

Tags: php, email

I am using this code. I get no error after clicking the send button, but I also receive no mail in my mail account:

```
        <?php
if($_POST["action"]=="sendmail_contact")
{
    $from=$_POST["email"];
    $to= "anikdatta2015@gmail.com"; 

    $subject='Prestige Limousines Contact Us Form Details ';
    $headers="MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers.="Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$headers.= "From:$from<$from>\r\n"; 

    $Message="";
    $Message.='<font face="Verdana" size="2"> Prestige Limousines Contact Us Form Details are as follows : <br><br></font>';
    $Message.='<font face="Verdana" size="2"><strong>Name</strong>: '.ucfirst($_POST["name"]).'</font><br><br>';
    $Message.='<font face="Verdana" size="2"><strong>E-mail</strong>: '.$_POST["email"].'</font><br><br>';
if($_POST["Subject"]!="") {
    $Message.='<font face="Verdana" size="2"><strong>Subject</strong>: '.$_POST["Subject"].'</font><br><br>';
}
    $Message.='<font face="Verdana" size="2"><strong>Message </strong>: '.$_POST["message"].'</font><br><br>';

 mail($to,$subject,$Message,$headers);
  include("member_contact_email.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you checked your junk mail? php `mail` is very hard to get to send to inboxes without the correct headers and server settings.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely issue, from what I can see, is this line here

```
$from=$_POST["email"];
```

Most mail servers are setup to block mail from being sent from other domains.   Meaning, you should always be sending mail from one of your email addresses that are valid on the domain.   You can then include the email from the POST somewhere in the body of the message.